# An inequality for elliptic functions

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, elliptic-functions

I want to show
$$2\,\text{cn}(x|k)^2 \,\text{dn}(x|k)^2\, \text{sn}(2
   x|k)-4\, \text{cn}(x|k)\, \text{cn}(2 x|k)
   \,\text{dn}(2 x|k)\, \text{dn}(x|k)
   \,\text{sn}(x|k)+k\, \text{cn}(x|k)^2
   \,\text{sn}(x|k)^2\, \text{sn}(2 x|k)-4 \,k
   \,\text{cn}(2 x|k)^2 \, \text{sn}(x|k)^2
   \,\text{sn}(2 x|k)+\text{dn}(x|k)^2
   \,\text{sn}(x|k)^2\, \text{sn}(2 x|k)-4
   \,\text{dn}(2 x|k)^2\, \text{sn}(x|k)^2
   \,\text{sn}(2 x|k)<0 $$
for $x\in(0,\pi/2)$ and $0<k<1$. Here $\text{sn}$, $\text{cn}$ and $\text{dn}$ are elliptic functions. This inequality has been verified by Mathematica using the Plot commend for several values of k. However, I cannot give a rigorous proof of it. Any suggestion, idea, or comment is welcome, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps I start with the double-angle formula for elliptic functions?

Comment: Why do you think that this is true?

Comment: Since it holds (verified by Mathematica) for a couple of k between $0$ and $1$, I believe this inequality is true for $0<k<1$.